# Randomly zero-out certain percentage of rows in a matrix in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have matrix that contains 5 rows and 4 columns:

```
arr = [[1,1,1,1],
       [2,2,2,2],
       [3,3,3,3],
       [4,4,4,4],
       [5,5,5,5]]
```

and I want to randomly zero=out/mask a certain percentage of this matrix row-wise. So if I set the percentage to be zeroed to 40%. I will get the following:

```
arr = [[0,0,0,0],
       [2,2,2,2],
       [3,3,3,3],
       [0,0,0,0],
       [5,5,5,5]]
```

what would be a good way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: did you try any code to achieve this?

Comment: I was thinking about generating a list of % random number in the range that corresponds to the length of the matrix  import random
random.sample(range(number), %). then zero out each index in this list with arr[list[#]] *= 0. Do you know of better ways to do this?

Comment: Is the question for Python or PyTorch ? Why is Pytorch tagged ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve your task is following (set `num_zero_rows`):

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7NCsIwEITveYo9JhJEWz36JCGUQlMNND9sUvx5@dhuK1Z3TjO77HzxmW/B16VYFwNmwNZ3wTHWIsIFlDpKkpYMllGVJG2SWpI2yUmSNslZkrRmzI@ueRkMDYZ7mkoqRs52j9klk/kCsU@ti4OZ3dXwwXg@QQkh4eeBEB9Wrg4adrAeKqsF2B4sWA/fAjMkA@ua4PqAy81fzQQa0fpMrpQ3)

```
import random

arr = [[1,1,1,1],
       [2,2,2,2],
       [3,3,3,3],
       [4,4,4,4],
       [5,5,5,5]]

num_zero_rows = 2
zero_idxs = set(random.sample(range(len(arr)), num_zero_rows))
arr = [([0] * len(arr[i]) if i in zero_idxs else arr[i])
    for i in range(len(arr))]

print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 2, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0], [4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5]]
```

---

Or a bit shorter/cleaner/faster variant of same code:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7LCgIxDEX3@YosWwmiM7oR/JJShgGrFqYPMiOiP19rnEXNWeXmcW9@LfcU@1J8yIkX5DFeUgAYmfGMxuxJsAT4K9OR0Cg9CY1yIKFRjiRYCxAfYXg7TgOn51xNOoBrYvTo42q/nceQJ6dqd3NqclHVOFoT/p3qk3yvI@PtN@zO4gbX7SppgMw@LnJcygc)

```
import random

arr = [[1,1,1,1],
       [2,2,2,2],
       [3,3,3,3],
       [4,4,4,4],
       [5,5,5,5]]

num_zero_rows = 2

for i in random.sample(range(len(arr)), num_zero_rows):
    arr[i] = [0] * len(arr[i])

print(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sample an indicator vector using [`torch.bernouli`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.bernoulli.html#torch.bernoulli):

```py
torch.bernoulli(0.4 * torch.ones_like(arr[:, :1]))
```

Once you have this vector, you can multiply it with `arr`:

```py
out = torch.bernoulli(0.4 * torch.ones_like(arr[:, :1])) * arr
```

And get the sampled array you want.

You should also look at [`dropout`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#dropout-functions) functions.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. If your matrix has `N` rows, pick a list of indecies from `[0, N-1]`

```
inds = np.arange(N)
M = int(N * 40 / 100)  # 40% of rows
inds = np.random.choice(inds, M, replace=False) # without replacement
```

.. then just assign zeros to the specific rows and all columns

```
arr[inds, :] = 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
import random

arr = [[1,1,1,1],
       [2,2,2,2],
       [3,3,3,3],
       [4,4,4,4],
       [5,5,5,5]]

for i in arr:
    if random.randint(0, 1): # if 1 is hit, the entire line will zero out
        for j in range(len(i)):
            i[j] = 0
```

output try 1:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1], 
[2, 2, 2, 2], 
[3, 3, 3, 3], 
[0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

output try 2:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], 
[2, 2, 2, 2], 
[0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0], 
[5, 5, 5, 5]]
```